# Using recursion to find the longest word in a sentence (Java)

Tags: java, recursion

For an assignment, I am supposed to find the longest word in a sentence using recursion. I wrote a method that takes the first two words of the sentence, compares them, and then takes the longer of the two and compares that to the next word in the rest of the sentence. My logic checks out, but the method does not work correctly. I think there is a fluke that takes out spaces, and that is why it is not working.

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence)
{
    if (sentence.indexOf(' ') == -1) {      // IF sentence only has one word
        return sentence;
    }

    String word1 =(sentence.indexOf(" ") != -1)? sentence.substring(0, sentence.indexOf(" ")):
                                                    sentence.substring(0);
    String temp = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(" ")+1);


    String word2 = null;
    String rest = null;
    if (sentence.indexOf(" ") != -1)    {
     word2 = (temp.indexOf(" ") != -1)? temp.substring(0, temp.indexOf(" ")+1):
                                            temp.substring(0);
     rest = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(" ")+1);
    }


    if (word1.length() > word2.length()) {
        return longestWord(word1 + rest);

    }

    if (word2.length() > word1.length())  {
        return longestWord(word2 + rest);

    }

    return sentence;


}
```

Comment: You invoke `indexOf(' ')` and `indexOf(" ")`; is that intentional?  If the first test passes, under what circumstances could the second fail?

Comment: When you say "does not work correctly" what do you mean? Providing some sample input/output would possibly be helpful.

Comment: @Jeff Input: The longest word is watermelon ; Output: watermelonwatermelon

Comment: Or Input : An aardvark is a cool pet ; Output: aardvarkapet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple of problems here, but I think that the one that's catching you is that you're setting `rest` to not have a space at the start, but then you're concatenating a word onto the start of it. So "a quick brown fox" -> "quickbrown fox".

In addition to that, though, if the two words are the same length then you're returning the whole sentence - instead you should make the last `if` statment an `else` statement and remove the final `return` statement.

**EDIT**: Although you probably don't want to throw away what you've got, you might find the recursive solution simpler if you reverse the focus: Instead of taking the first two words each time, take just the first word and compare it against the longest word of the remainder:

```
longestWord(String sentence) {
    if (sentence.indexOf(' ') == -1) {      // IF sentence only has one word
        return sentence;
    }
    String firstWord = getFirstWord(sentence);//how you're doing it now
    String rest = getRest(sentence);//Just the sentence without the first word (and first space...)
    String secondWord = longestWord(rest);
    return firstWord.length >= secondWord.length ? firstWord : secondWord;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to do it recursively: split the string into words, and then do a recursive invocation of this method, like this:

```
string longest(string sentence) {
    return longestRecursive(sentence.Split(' '), 0, "");
}

string longestRecursive(string[] words, int index, string longestSoFar) {
    // This should be very easy to implement:
    // If index == words.Length, longestSoFar is your answer
    // Check words[0] against longestSoFar, and make a recursive invocation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If sentence is String.

Split the sentence using String.Split(" ");

Store the result in string array.

Use recursion to find the longest string using .length.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence) {
        return longestWord(sentence, "");
    }

    private static String longestWord(String sentence, String longestWord) {
        int i = sentence.indexOf(' ');
        if (i == -1) {
            return sentence.length() > longestWord.length() ? sentence : longestWord;
        }
        longestWord = i > longestWord.length() ? sentence.substring(0, i) : longestWord;
        sentence = sentence.substring(i + 1);
        return longestWord(sentence, longestWord);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't do tail call optimization, so this could easily blow the stack. But you asked for recursive (and in a language with TCO, it's stack neutral). Note that it only ever constructs a single string.

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence) {
    return longestWordHelper(sentence, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

String longestWordHelper(String sentence,
                         int best_len, int best_end,
                         int cur_len, int cur) {
  if (cur == sentence.length()) 
    if (cur_len > best_len)
      return sentence.substring(cur_end - cur_len, cur_len);
    else
      return sentence.substring(best_end - best_len, best_len);
  if (isSpace(sentence.charAt(cur)))
    if (cur_len > best_len)
      return longestWordHelper(sentence, cur_len, cur, 0, cur + 1);
    else
      return longestWordHelper(sentence, best_len, best_end, 0, cur + 1);
  else
    return longestWordHelper(sentence, best_len, best_end, cur_len + 1, cur + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package MujeebWorkspace.sampleprograms;

class javaMujeeb{       
static String actualstring= "Today is a very good day";
static String[] splitstring = actualstring.split(" ");

public static void main(String [] args){
    LongWord();
    ShortWord();    }

public static void LongWord() {     
    String longword = "";
    for (int i=0; i<=splitstring.length-1; i++){    
    if (longword.length()<splitstring[i].length())
        longword = splitstring[i];  }
    System.out.println(longword);   }

    public static void ShortWord(){
        String shortword = "  ";
        for (int i=0; i<=splitstring.length-1; i++){        
        if (splitstring[i].length()<shortword.length())
            shortword = splitstring[i];         }       
        System.out.println(shortword);      }
```

}